# 404 displayed on the front end of the spring cloud project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

When doing the graduation project, I tried to use spring cloud to build the framework. In the process of building, due to the limitations of self-study, I did not fully understand some knowledge points, so I encountered many problems. Most of these problems have been solved through the sharing of predecessors on the Internet, but now when I encounter this problem, I have searched a lot of relevant materials on the Internet but failed to find a solution. So I'm asking for help.

After the project starts, when you click on the port Numbers 40999 and 40888 in the run dashboard, the Google browser displays 404, as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lemVn.png) 
But when I access it from the Eureka page, it works
And when I use Google or postman, the page still displays 404 and the error message above.

Many related problems were found on the Internet, including application. Properties configuration and startup class location.
Still hope somebody can help me.thanks.
This is my test controller.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RequestMapping("/test")
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

This is the application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=client
server.port=40999
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:20000/eureka/
```

[This is the picture of console log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHgDu.png)

Comment: 404 is returned because there is no resource mapped for the url you are using, or you are using a wrong mapping to access the resource. You need to give more context about the problem you have. e.g : upload a screenshot of the request you are using in postman. Add all the stuff that you think might help us to figure out the problem. Our community is here to help you out.

Comment: When i found this question,i create a testController.Its only return a String as response value.But i cant get it in google or postman.The url is http://localhost:40999/test/hello which i used in postman.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: How did you set the port to 40999

Comment: The server.port = 40999 in application.properties.

Comment: Upload your `application.properties` file

Comment: #服务名称
spring.application.name=client
#端口号
server.port=40999
#注册中心
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:20000/eureka/

Comment: These are content in application.properties.

Comment: Add the full file to your question

Comment: Sorry,this is my first time using it.And i dont know how to upload the file.Everything in the file is in the previous reply

Comment: Hi, you can use `Ctrl+K` to insert code snippets to your questions. Or you can follow the [editing guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information. Please add your controller class.

Comment: Thank you very much.I update my question and copy the code in application.properties and controller class.Your answer give me too many help.

Comment: Have you configured any spring security features? Also, Can you copy the console log and post it? Everything seems to be okay with your code. In the meantime, try updating this line `@RequestMapping("/hello")` to `@GetMapping("/hello")`

Comment: I try to update RequestMapping to GetMapping,but still get 404.And i add the picture of console log to question.

Comment: I can't say anything anymore without taking a look at your code. If this is really important to you, I can take a look at your project if you share it with me. I can try and give it a go.

Comment: OK.I will send you my project.How to sending?Can you give me your e-mail?

Comment: can you upload it to github and share the link?